# In Angular 7 - how can I disabled chrome auto fill and manage password select list

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular6, angular7

In Angular 7 - how can I disabled chrome auto fill and manage password select list?

**Things I've tried:**

- autocomplete="off"
- autocomplete="false"

**This is my form:**

```
<form class="col-12" [formGroup]="form" autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <label>Email*</label>
  <input type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="" class="col-12 mb1 field">    

  <label>Password*</label>
  <input type="password" formControlName="password" placeholder="" class="col-12 mb1 field">

  <label>Confirm Password*</label>
  <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword" class="col-12 mb2 field">


  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-primary col-12" prevent-double-submit>Get Started</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this old but effective solution  - `autocomplete="new-password"`

[Chromium Issue 370363 reference](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370363#c7)

[Stack overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: I just want to turn chrome auto fill off on all my forms and their field types

Comment: Does this solution works ? `autocomplete="new-password"`

Comment: But what if it’s a none password input?

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this issue by 2 ways,

1) Set `autocomplete=null` in your HTML.

2) If you are not interested in using null in HTML, you need to create a directive.

```
ng g d Autocomplete
```

and modify AutocompleteDirective class as following:

```
private element: HTMLInputElement;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
  this.element = elRef.nativeElement;
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.element.autocomplete = null //this will override default autocomplete.
}
```

and in your template:

```
<input appAutocomplete type="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="" class="col-12 mb1 field">
```

Comment: Weird, which Angular version do you use ?

Comment: I think I've made a mistake. Corrected it and uploaded [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eetoke).

Comment: I'm using angular 7